# WebApi verify uploaded files

Tags: c#, .net-core, webapi

I have a WEBAPI that uploads multiple files. What is the best way to verify if the files made it successfully to the server? Right now the try catch doesn't catch anything even when the files does not make it to the server. Forexample, using postman, when I don't provide a "Key", the file does not get uploaded. I just get a "Success" code but this is not correct.

[image]

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("/api/FileUpload")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(List<IFormFile> file, CancellationToken cancellationtoken)
    {
        var result = await WriteFile(file);
        return Ok(result);
    }

    private async Task<string> WriteFile(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        //string filename = "";
    
        try
        {

            var result = new List<UploadFilesInfo>();

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var extension = "." + file.FileName.Split('.')[file.FileName.Split('.').Length - 1];
                //filename = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + extension;


                //var filepath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Uploaded\\Files");

                var filepath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "UploadedFiles");

                if (!Directory.Exists(filepath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath);
                }

                var exactpath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "UploadedFiles", file.FileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(exactpath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }



            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ("File Not uploaded!");
        }
        return("Success");
        //
    }

}
```

Comment: So... you're asking how to implement input validation?

Comment: That's because in `WriteFile()` you catch all possible exceptions and return a string as status code (!) and in `UploadFile()` you simply always return with `Ok()`. You _may_ check the response body for the error string (client side) but it's a bit pointless, catch the (appropriate!) exceptions in `UploadFiles()` and return the appropriate error code (which is probably not 400). Also, no need to return "success" for 200, simply return 204 without body.
Side note: to combine/create a path with unvalidated client side data is a _bit_ risky.

Comment: You may not get any response when TLS fails.  TLS is used when request is HTTPS (secure) .  TLS sets up an encryption keys and is performed before the HTTP Request is sent.  When TLS fails no Request is sent and then you do not get back a response with a status.